# RxJava Subject unable to resolve generic consumer

Tags: java, generics, rx-java2

**Background:**

The following code is from a generic bus from my code that will delegate object of different types (all of them are extending from BaseEvent class) to different consumers.

**Problem:**

```
   private static PublishSubject<? extends BaseEvent> mPublishSubject;
    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public void subscribeToEventBus(Class subscribingClass, Class eventToSubscribeTo, Consumer<? extends BaseEvent> subscriber) {
        mPublishSubject.subscribe(subscriber);// <---- ERROR HERE
        mEventBusSubscribersList.add(new EventBusInfo(subscribingClass, eventToSubscribeTo, subscriber));
    }
```

***Error:***

```
            error: no suitable method found for subscribe(Consumer<CAP#1>)
method Observable.subscribe(Consumer<? super CAP#2>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Consumer<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Consumer<? super CAP#2>)
method Observable.subscribe(Observer<? super CAP#2>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Consumer<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Observer<? super CAP#2>)
where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
CAP#1 extends BaseEvent from capture of ? extends BaseEvent
CAP#2 extends BaseEvent from capture of ? extends BaseEvent
```

**Objective:**

I want Consumer<> to accept all the classes that extend from BaseEvent.

I'm not quite sure what exactly am I doing wrong considering my primitive knowledge of Java generics.

Comment: Please provide the definition of `mPublishSubject`.

Comment: @akarnokd I've updated the question

Comment: Try `PublishSubject<BaseEvent>` without the `? extends`. Java's generics sometimes doesn't allow certain co- and contravariant use cases.